# Invalid conversion from char to String* C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

```
String* substr(String* str, int start, int end)
{   
   String* substring = new String;
   for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
   {
       substring =  str->text[i];
   }   

   return substring;
}
```

I need to store the substring located in the text array member of my String struct. The method is supposed to take part of the array(separated by delimiters) and store it in variables str1 and str2 then compare them. I am having problems with the 6th line where the string is being substring is supposed to be created and stored.

Comment: Show declaration of `String`.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay String is a struct declared in my .h file it contains const char* text and int sz;

Comment: You need to change it to just `char *text` (remove the const) and also allocate with new: `substring.text = new char[end-start+1]`. And don't forget to add EOS after the copy.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp correction: `substring->text`

Answer (score 1):

Since no one else has answered...
First change your struct:

```
struct String {
    char* text;    // Removed const
    int sz;
};
```

Now, change your function

```
String* substr(String* str, int start, int end)
{   
   String* substring = new String;

   //Alloc enough space to hold chars + EOS
   substring->text = new char[end - start + 1]; 
   // Save string length - does not include EOS
   substring->sz = end - start;       

   for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
   {
       // TODO: Error checking should be added to make sure it doesn't go
       // beyond original string bounds

       // Copy the substring
       substring->text[i - start] =  str->text[i];
   }
   // Add end of string
   substring->text[substring->sz] = '\0';

   return substring;
}
```

Note, doing it this way, you later need to delete both the array and the struct:

```
delete [] substring->text;
delete substring;
```

Or, you can just use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)...